# Toast is not displayed when completing the quest

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

Toast is not displayed when completing the quest.

For example, as shown below toast

http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Google-Play-Games-In-Game-Toast-2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play Games does not automatically display a toast for a completed Quest like it does with an Achievement.  Instead, you should register a Quest listener that implements `onQuestCompleted()` in your `Activity` as described [on this page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quests).

This is because a Quest is something that your app can choose to customize, specifically through the reward data you associate with the quest.  You should handle the quest completion event and give the user the appropriate award.  If you'd like to also display a Toast, you can do that with a normal `Toast.makeText(...)` call in the callback or even an `AlertDialog` styled by your application.